# RecyclerView with SnapHelper, item is not snapped after scrollToPosition

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView in my activity and a LinearSnapHelper attached to it:

```
TimePickerAdapter timePickerAdapter = new TimePickerAdapter(hours);
recyclerView = (RecyclerView) root.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

final SnapHelper snapHelper = new LinearSnapHelper();
snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
```

The problem is that when I want to initially scroll to a specific item, the snap helper is not being triggered to attach the item (see the image):

```
recyclerView.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(timePickerAdapter.getCurrentPosition());
```

When I scroll with my hand it starts to work as expected.
Any solutions to this?

[image]

Comment: with `com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.0` it works just fine

Comment: I have 25.0.1. Maybe there is something else?

Comment: hmm, no idea really...

Answer (score 14):

`SnapHelper` rely on `RecyclerView.OnFlingListener#onFling()` or `RecyclerView.OnScrollListener#onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE)` to trigger snap action.

But `scrollToPosition()` will not tigger above callback. You can invoke `smoothScrollBy(1, 0)` after `scrollToPosition()` to trigger `SnapHelper` to scroll.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered the same issue - for me using `recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(pos)` instead of `recyclerView.scrollToPosition(pos)` did the trick

Comment: Thanks for the reply, does it also work for you if the item to which you are scrolling is already visible? For me ``smoothScrollToPosition`` doesn't do anything in that case.

Comment: In case of 1000 items it will scroll about 15 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

If items have the same width and space between them also the same you can use this for initial scroll

```
recyclerView.apply {
   post {
       val dx = initialPosition * (itemWidth + itemSpace)
       scrollBy(dx, 0)
   }
}
```